Issue setting SecureConnectionLevel in rsreportserver.config for SSRS for https redirect
So, to cut a long story short, we've installed the SSL certs across the environment. I've configured SSRS via the config tool to allow for an HTTPS connection. All is working, the https web portal works, etc. I can browse the reports with the https link and the lock is showing in the browser.
However, when setting SecureConnectionLevel (to either 1 or 3), the web portal URL in the config tool changes to "unknown" and the certificate becomes "unknown" too. Is there any way to fix this or does someone have another method for implementing a https redirect?
